# setting opacity on a div, without effecting other divs

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to set an `opacity` to my background div, but all the content inside gets an opacity too. I don't want this.
I tried to fix it with pseudo elements but it didn't work out, I can fix this problem by adding a second background div and setting a `height` and `position` to that div, but I don't want to set a height for a div.

How can I fix this without adding a second div and height?

You can see my demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d2shse4c/embedded/result/)

Comment: if its the child of the div with opacity you have not a chance to do this (edited my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use an RGBA value:

```
html {
  background-color: red;
}
#login {
  width: 365px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 37px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d2shse4c/2/

Comment: Easy as that! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What i usually make to do this is sibling divs with position absolute:

```
<div id="page">
   <div id="content">
      TEXT here
   </div>
   <div id="back" style="position:absolute; opacity:0.5; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height: 100%; background-color:#000000;">
   </div>
   <div id="anotherText" style="position:absolute; width:100px; height: 100px">
   TEXT
   </div>
</div>
```

and so on....

OR:
Set a png background image on the parent div!

Comment: As I said in my question. I don't want this.